# MySQL Using a select to update multiple columns and records in a table

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

I've just added two columns to a table I was working on, and want to put numerical values in those two columns based on the value of another column. I need to do this for all of the records in the database (MySQL), can someone help me with this please?

The table (t1) looks like

```
spectra (varchar, primary key),
value REAL,(This is the one to use)
new_val 1 REAL
new_val 2 REAL
```

I'm thinking it should look something like;

```
update t1 set (new_val1,new_val2)=(select value*1.5,value*2 from t1) as t2 where t1.spectra=t2.spectra;
```

Any suggestions please?
Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

```
update t1 set new_val1 = value*1.5, new_val2 = value*2;
```

Comment: Please consider selecting an answer on your questions.